# Insert multiple rows using array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a set of rows consist an array. I want to insert the data in database but when i insert this, it inserts data of last row in database.

**Input**
[image: Input]

**Output in database**
[image: output in database]

**HTML**

```
    <select class="price" name="orderedproduct[]" id="orderedproduct'+counter+'" row="'+counter+'">
    <option>Select Ordered Product</option>
    <option value="5">VITANKA</option>
    <option value="14">INCAPROT</option>
    <option value="15">METHOLIP</option>
    </select>

    <input type="text" name="productqty[]" id="productqty'+counter+'" class="gui-input txtQuantity" placeholder="Quantity" row="'+counter+'">

    <input type="text" name="orderedamount[]" id="orderedamount'+counter+'" class="gui-input orderamount" placeholder="Total Amount" row="'+counter+'">

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Report">
```

**PHP**

```
$sql3="";
if($_POST['orderedproduct'])
{
//$productqty=$_POST['productqty'];
//var_dump($productqty);
                                            //$orderedamount=$_POST['orderedamount'];
//var_dump($orderedamount);
foreach($_POST['productqty'] as $productqty1)
{
$productqty=$productqty1;   
}

foreach($_POST['orderedamount'] as $ordredamount1)
{
$orderedamount= $ordredamount1; 
}

foreach($_POST['orderedproduct'] as $orderedproduct)
{

$sql3.="( (SELECT MAX(D_C_R.DCR_ID) FROM D_C_R),$orderedproduct,$productqty,$orderedamount),";

}
//echo implode("",$productqty);
$sql3="INSERT INTO ORDER_TABLE(ORDER_TABLE.DCR, ORDER_TABLE.PRODUCT, ORDER_TABLE.QTY, ORDER_TABLE.AMOUNT)   VALUES".trim($sql3,',');

$res3=mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: Really dangerous queries....Ready to get injected ;)

Comment: And really strange loops. They do not iterate over variables OP thinks they iterate.

Comment: The `$productqty` and `$ordredamount` variables will always be the last ones of the `$_POST['orderedamount']` and `$_POST['productqty']` array. You need to put more thought into the logic of how this works. Maybe store them in a 2-D Array?